# python open 関数

Tags: python

open関数についての質問です。openは第一引数にファイル名を挿入するものと理解しているのですが、
例えば

```
iniDir1 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
filepath1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir1)
```

として絶対パスが取得できたときに

```
open(filepath1,"r")
```

というプログラムで開けないものかと思っていましたが、作成したプログラムでエラーが発生してます。
この場合open関数はファイル名を挿入することにしか対応していないのでしょうか？
それとも別の関数があるのでしょうか？
教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: filedialog とは何者ですか？また、 filepath1 は絶対パスですか？この情報を質問文に追記お願いします

Comment: エラーが発生したのならそのエラーメッセージを記載してください。それが最も重要な情報となります。

Comment: `tkinter` ですかね。 実行可能で完全なスクリプト例を掲示いただけますか？

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/222413

Comment: 元のプログラムを幾分か省略して質問しています。この質問の本質はopenの第一引数にはファイル名を挿入することしかできないのかということでした。質問の仕方が悪かったです。すいません